# New iOS Project created using cordova 3.8.0 missing de.lproj, en.lproj ,localizable.strings file in Resources folder

Tags: ios, cordova, localization, xcode6, phonegap-plugins

I have created new project using apache cordova 3.8.0.it is working properly on all devices.But there is one problem the Resources folder does not contain en.lproj, de.lproj and Localizable.strings file in it.
       So how can i set localization for default English language?

In screenshot you will see that there are folders (marked as red )named de.lproj,en.lporj etc , they are missing in new cordova 3.8.0 project.In green mark we have to set localization by default to English.So how i set localization there. OR Please tell me there is no need to set localization and these folders in new cordova project.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706851/i-added-a-localization-in-xcode-removed-it-and-now-my-storyboard-is-gone or http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014 and http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/

Answer (score 1):

This was previously not possible until recently when the PBXVariant Groups was added to node-xcode.

You may be able to use the cordova plugin [cordova-plugin-localization-strings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-localization-strings) to create the Localizable.strings required for the different locales in your Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of creating an Apache Cordova application is that you wrap a webpage as a native app. Therefor, any localisation or langauges change will have to be done inside your web/html/javascript app. So maybe you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795593/xcode-phonegap-localization).